# Isomorphism mapping from $\mathbb R^3$ to $\mathbb P_2(\mathbb R)$

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra, linear-transformations, vector-space-isomorphism

Can you give an example of an isomorphism mapping from $\mathbb R^3 \to \mathbb P_2(\mathbb R)$(degree-2 polynomials)?

I understand that to show isomorphism you can show both injectivity and surjectivity, or you could also just show that an inverse matrix exists.

My issue is that I don't think you can represent the transformation with a matrix because of the polynomial space.

How would you come to proving isomorphism without the use of matrix representations?

Comment: What is $\mathbb{P}_2(\mathbb{R})$? Not all symbols are universally known notation.

Comment: @TrevorGunn I used that to represent polynomials of degree 2

Comment: Degree $2$ polynomials is not a vector space. $x^2+1-x^2=1$ that have not degree 2.

Comment: Degree _at most_ $2$, I should think.

Answer (score 1):

What about$$\begin{array}{rccc}\psi\colon&\mathbb R^3&\longrightarrow&P_2(\mathbb R)\\&(a,b,c)&\mapsto&a+bx+cx^2?\end{array}$$It is linear, injective and surjective.

Comment: that's the example I was thinking but I am not sure how to show the injectivity and surjection for this example.

Comment: both spaces are $3$ dimensional.  so it suffices to show the kernel is $0$.

Comment: It's just that $a+bx+cx^2$ is the null polynomial when and only when $a=b=c=0$.

Comment: ok cool I think I get it, so for surjective you'd show that the dimension of domain and range are equal and for injective you would show that the quadratic has only 1 unique solution for 0?

Comment: I don't know which quadratic you have in mind, but I proved injectivity in my previous comment. And any injective linear map between two vector spaces with the same dimension is surjective too.

Comment: I just meant that the linear combination $a + bx + cx^2$ as the quadratic equation. But, showing that it is unique shows that it is injective right?

Comment: Yes, each polynomial with degree smaller than or equal to $2$ can be written in a unique way as $a+bx+cx^2$ and therefore the null polynomial can only be written as $0+0\times x+0\times x^2$, which shows that $\psi$ is injective.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you mean the polynomials of degree less than or equal to $2$, it is a three dimensional space, with basis $\{1,x,x^2\}$.  So, just send basis vectors to basis vectors:

$$e_1\to1,e_2\to x,e_3\to x^2$$.

The matrix, rel these two standard bases, is the identity.